# How to validate recursion objects in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, validation, recursion

How to validate recursive nested objects in Laravel 5+

I have structure of balance of the company. There is a pattern

```
<row>: {
name
digit
rows: [<row>]
}
```

The example of the json structure

```
{
    "balance_data": {
        "rows": [
            {
                "name": "aktiva",
                "digit": "5555.33",
                "rows": [
                    {
                        "name": "balance catalog 1",
                        "digit": "1234.12",
                        "rows": [
                            {
                                "name": "balance subcatalog name 1",
                                "digit": "4321.21",
                                "rows": []
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "balance subcatalog name 2",
                                "digit": "4321.21",
                                "rows": []
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "balance catalog 2",
                        "digit": "1234.12",
                        "rows": [
                            {
                                "name": "balance subcatalog name 3",
                                "digit": "4321.21",
                                "rows": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How i can validate digit as *required* in all nested and subnested objects?

Comment: I don't know if this would work for your case but have a look through this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#validating-arrays and give this a try (no promises): `'*.digit' => 'required'`

Comment: @user3532758 that won't work since there's multiple levels of nesting

Comment: @PavelLint it was a long shot anyways. :)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to write a custom validator for that. Check out [this section of the docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules).

Comment: This answer is not very generous.  It looks more like a traffic directing comment than an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function myFunction($value, $key) 
{ 
    // do validation, this will be called for every key, recursively
} 

$arr=array("balance_data"=>array("row"=>"", array("row"=>"2"))); 

array_walk_recursive($arr, "myFunction"); 

?>
```

This can be achieved using inbuild `array_walk_recursive` function of php